# Spark Structured Streaming Session Window Restrictions

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-window-function

I'am going through the [spark structured streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#starting-streaming-queries:%7E:text=Note%20that%20there%20are%20some%20restrictions%20when%20you%20use%20session%20window%20in%20streaming%20query%2C%20like%20below%3A) and kind of did not understood why there are restrictions regarding the session window.
Please explain the below statements why is such:

> Note that there are some restrictions when you use session window in
> streaming query, like below:
>
> “Update mode” as output mode is not supported. There should be at
> least one column in addition to session_window in grouping key. For
> batch query, global window (only having session_window in grouping
> key) is supported.
>
> By default, Spark does not perform partial aggregation for session
> window aggregation, since it requires additional sort in local
> partitions before grouping. It works better for the case there are
> only few number of input rows in same group key for each local
> partition, but for the case there are numerous input rows having same
> group key in local partition, doing partial aggregation can still
> increase the performance significantly despite additional sort.